# Incorrect console output after previous output

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Task: output the number in hexadecimal form to the console. After that print some string (let it be "String after num").
The first part is successful, but the second is not.

- The input number is stored in memory by the `num` label.
- String is stored in memory by the `line` label.
- String length - `lines`.

Code:

```
global _start

section .data
num   db 01111110b
temp  db 0

line  db 10, "String after num", 10
lines equ $-line 

section .text
_start:
    call write_hex          ; write num in hex format

    mov     eax, 4          ; write "Hello world!"
    mov     ebx, 1          ;
    mov     ecx, line       ;
    mov     edx, lines      ;
    int     80H             ;

    mov     eax, 1          ; exit
    xor     ebx, ebx
    int     80H

write_hex:
    mov     eax, [num]
    mov     [temp], eax
    shr     byte [num], 4
    call    to_hex_digit     
    call    write_digit

    mov     eax, [temp]
    mov     [num], eax

    and     byte [num], 1111b
    call    to_hex_digit
    call    write_digit
    ret

to_hex_digit:
    add     [num], byte '0'
    cmp     [num], byte '9'
    jle     end
    add     [num], byte 7
end: ret

write_digit:
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, num
    mov     edx, 1
    int     80H
    ret
```

Output:

[image: output]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You only allocate a single byte for `temp` but write a dword (4 bytes) there hence overwriting the beginning of the string that follows it in memory. Use `al` instead of `eax`.

Comment: @Jester, thanks for your help! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an invalid register to store a temporary value. I replaced the register which will work with the `temp` from `eax` to `al`. See Jester's answer.